# Eloquent relationship for related products

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

As an example, suppose I sell air conditioners and air filters. They are all products in my product table. But I also have a related_products table for which filters go with each air conditioner where product_id is the AC and filter_id is the corresponding product_id in the product table for the filters:

| product_id | filter_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |

How are these relations defined in Laravel Eloquent? This seems almost like a pivot table referring to a single products table. The related_products table doesn't have an associated Model (I don't think) so would I try to define this relationship all in the Product model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `product_id` and `filter_id` are pointing to records in `products`, this would be a self-referential many-to-many relationship, with `related_products` as the pivot between `products.product_id == related_products.product_id` and `products.product_id == related_products.filter_id`:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.

Only difference between this and the documentation is you'd define the relationship twice in your `Product` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Product extends Model {
  public function relatedProducts(): BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'related_products', 'id', 'product_id');
  }

  public function relatedFilters(): BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'related_products', 'id', 'filter_id');
  }
}
```

*Note: you might need to reverse the order of `'id', 'product_id'` and `'id', 'filter_id'`, as I don't recall which is the local key (`products.id`) and which is the foreign key on the pivot table (`related_products.product_id` and `related_products.filter_id`), and I don't have a database available to test and confirm this*

Also, by default, a `many-to-many` doesn't use an intermediate Model in Laravel, i.e. there is no need to define a `class RelatedProduct extends Model { ... }`. You *can* if you'd like to, and Laravel supports this, but it's not a requirement:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models